# Getting value of a hidden element in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I have a hidden input field in HTML, it contains SomeValue:

```
  <input id="event_id" type="hidden"> SomeValue </input>
```

I need SomeValue in server-side.

Is there a SHtml method I can use? The following code should get the value on submit, I need the value once the page is loaded.

```
"event_id" #> SHtml.onSubmit(id = _)
```

Comment: Have you tried `SHtml.hidden(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

In the template you can just write

```
<input id="event_id"></input>
```

And in the snippet you can use the `SHtml.hidden` method:

```
SHtml.hidden(() => println("hidden field"))
```

Comment: But how to store the value in var id?

Comment: I think I didn't completely understood what you want. Can you edit your question with what to want to do, and when? For exemple get the text in the hidden field on submit, or get this text once it is modified...

Comment: I need the value on load or on change.

Comment: In fact, when I think of it, I don't know if it is possible. Usually, you use lift to set stuff in templates, so you don't know to get some content back. However it should be possible, but I don't know how. 
My opinion is to use a javascript callback to give the value to lift when setting it in the hidden part (or instead of setting it).

Comment: Chris, I have realized that it was not the best approach. I still do not know if it possible, anyway I go for using SHtml staff in Lift. Thanks for your help!